# How to debug C-shared library (written in Go) - it hangs on net call

Tags: c, go, shared-libraries, stack-trace

Go code with *http.Post()*. If I build exe, it's OK. If I build C shared library *-buildmode=c-shared*, it hangs on https.Post().

I've tried *strace -fp PID*:

```
futex(0x7f618b2c1cd0, FUTEX_WAKE, 1)    = 0
futex(0xc820022110, FUTEX_WAIT, 0, NULL
```

I've tried to add profiler:

```
http.ListenAndServe("localhost:6060", nil)
http.Post()
```

But again it hangs on http.Post and profiler was blocked as well (it was listening, but not response from 6060 port). I've sent SIGQUIT signal - stack trace:

```
SIGQUIT: quit
PC=0x7f0cad5c9081 m=1

goroutine 0 [idle]:
runtime.futex(0xc820022110, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x7f0c00000000, 0x7f0cad577879, 0x0, 0x0, 0x7f0cad577ae8, 0xc820022110, ...)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/sys_linux_amd64.s:288 +0x21
runtime.futexsleep(0xc820022110, 0xc800000000, 0xffffffffffffffff)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/os1_linux.go:39 +0x53
runtime.notesleep(0xc820022110)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/lock_futex.go:142 +0xa8
runtime.stoplockedm()
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc1.go:1268 +0xb2
runtime.schedule()
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc1.go:1590 +0x72
runtime.park_m(0xc820000600)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc1.go:1698 +0x191
runtime.mcall(0x7f0cad5c722a)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:204 +0x53

goroutine 17 [IO wait, locked to thread]:
runtime.gopark(0x7f0cada4a878, 0x7f0ca594b198, 0x7f0cad993b20, 0x7, 0x1b, 0x5)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:185 +0x169 fp=0xc820041868 sp=0xc820041840
runtime.netpollblock(0x7f0ca594b170, 0x72, 0x7f0cac21e050)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/netpoll.go:338 +0x160 fp=0xc8200418b0 sp=0xc820041868
net.runtime_pollWait(0x7f0ca594b170, 0x72, 0xc82000a1c0)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/netpoll.go:157 +0x62 fp=0xc8200418d0 sp=0xc8200418b0
net.(*pollDesc).Wait(0xc82011c140, 0x72, 0x0, 0x0)
        /usr/local/go/src/net/fd_poll_runtime.go:73 +0x3c fp=0xc8200418f0 sp=0xc8200418d0
net.(*pollDesc).WaitRead(0xc82011c140, 0x0, 0x0)
        /usr/local/go/src/net/fd_poll_runtime.go:78 +0x38 fp=0xc820041918 sp=0xc8200418f0
net.(*netFD).accept(0xc82011c0e0, 0x0, 0x7f0ca594b268, 0xc8200b4440)
        /usr/local/go/src/net/fd_unix.go:408 +0x27e fp=0xc820041a18 sp=0xc820041918
net.(*TCPListener).AcceptTCP(0xc8200b8050, 0xc820041ab0, 0x0, 0x0)
        /usr/local/go/src/net/tcpsock_posix.go:254 +0x4f fp=0xc820041a78 sp=0xc820041a18
net/http.tcpKeepAliveListener.Accept(0xc8200b8050, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
        /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2135 +0x43 fp=0xc820041ab0 sp=0xc820041a78
net/http.(*Server).Serve(0xc8200b20c0, 0x7f0ca594b230, 0xc8200b8050, 0x0, 0x0)
        /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1887 +0xb5 fp=0xc820041b98 sp=0xc820041ab0
net/http.(*Server).ListenAndServe(0xc8200b20c0, 0x0, 0x0)
        /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1877 +0x138 fp=0xc820041c28 sp=0xc820041b98
net/http.ListenAndServe(0x7f0cad9a6ae0, 0xe, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
        /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1967 +0x91 fp=0xc820041c50 sp=0xc820041c28
main.Code(0xc8201122a0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/jangaraj/zabbix-module/zabbix_module.go:152 +0x94 fp=0xc820041d58 sp=0xc820041c50
github.com/cavaliercoder/g2z.route_item(0x7ffe7bc803e0, 0x7ffe7bc80c90, 0x0)
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/cavaliercoder/g2z/router.go:65 +0xc2a fp=0xc820041ed0 sp=0xc820041d58
runtime.call32(0x0, 0x7ffe7bc802d8, 0x7ffe7bc80360, 0x18)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:437 +0x40 fp=0xc820041ef8 sp=0xc820041ed0
runtime.cgocallbackg1()
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/cgocall.go:252 +0x110 fp=0xc820041f30 sp=0xc820041ef8
runtime.cgocallbackg()
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/cgocall.go:177 +0xd9 fp=0xc820041f90 sp=0xc820041f30
runtime.cgocallback_gofunc(0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:801 +0x5d fp=0xc820041fa0 sp=0xc820041f90
runtime.goexit()
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1696 +0x1 fp=0xc820041fa8 sp=0xc820041fa0

goroutine 18 [syscall, locked to thread]:
runtime.goexit()
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1696 +0x1

goroutine 5 [chan receive]:
github.com/golang/glog.(*loggingT).flushDaemon(0x7f0cadd99bc0)
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/golang/glog/glog.go:882 +0x69
created by github.com/golang/glog.init.1
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/golang/glog/glog.go:410 +0x299

rax    0xca
rbx    0x0
rcx    0xffffffffffffffff
rdx    0x0
rdi    0xc820022110
rsi    0x0
rbp    0x1
rsp    0x7ffe7bc801a8
r8     0x0
r9     0x0
r10    0x0
r11    0x286
r12    0x4
r13    0x7f0cada47090
r14    0xd
r15    0x8
rip    0x7f0cad5c9081
rflags 0x286
cs     0x33
fs     0x0
gs     0x0
```

How to debug/solve this problem? Code looks OK - standard executable binary returns correct value. Only C shared library version has some issue. Another methods from shared library, which don't use http.post()/net.Dial() are OK.

Original issue: https://github.com/cavaliercoder/g2z/issues/5

Comment: Any update on this ? Did you find a solution / workaround ? I'm facing a similar issue ...

Comment: No, I didn't find any workaround.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok I solved this for my use case, you might be in a similar situation.

When you link your Go c-shared library to your C or C++ application, the Go runtime is loaded when you start the application (you can verify this, in `func init()` for example, it's called directly when you start your app). Then, if you fork a process and use the Go library, you will have unpredictable behaviour.
Basically, you must load the Go shared library after fork and can't rely on it once you forked. Using `dlopen` and `dlsym` will allow you to control when the Go runtime get loaded.

Comment: I realize this is quite some time after you originally encountering the problem, but can you clarify what "Basically, you must load the Go shared library after fork and can't rely on it once you forked." means? Does this mean that you're safe if you load the library after the fork?

Comment: Hey @rmonjo, I ran into the same problem while writing a PAM (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluggable_authentication_module). As mansfield asked, could you how one could control the point in time when to load the shared library?

Comment: It's been a while on an abandoned side project but this was working: https://github.com/robinmonjo/ngx_http_l/blob/master/src/ngx_http_set_backend/ngx_http_set_backend_module.c#L44

Comment: For other folks coming across, here https://github.com/zabbix-tools/g2z/issues/5 and here https://github.com/golang/go/issues/15556 the problem is well described and there will be no solution if you dont have the fork/dlopen order under control :/