# http.Client hangs when used from a cgo-built shared library

Tags: apache, go, cgo

I'm writing an Apache Module in Go, everything works fine up until the point the code tries to use `http.Client` to POST data to a remote server.

I've extracted the relevant code into a simple `main.go` test case and it works as expected so the issue does not *appear* to be in my `http.Client` configuration.

There is an old [golang-nuts thread](https://groups.google.com/g/golang-nuts/c/AoCgdBbxR94/m/zdrtAT7wcH0J) discussing issues with cgo's DNS code, I've substituted an IP address for the domain name and still no luck.

Has anyone else seen this problem with cgo?

Comment: I don't recall what it will do offhand in a shared library, but you could try sending the process a SIGQUIT and see if you can get the runtime to dump the stack traces to pinpoint what is blocked. You could also just forgo the cgo dns resolver and see if that changes the behavior at all.

Comment: gdb shows the thread waiting on a mutex, nothing interesting into the app which makes me think it's been spun out into a go routine. I'm passing in an IP address to avoid the DNS resolver, if that doesn't work I don't have any apparent options as I have to use cgo for the Apache glue.

Comment: If you're talking about the cgo resolver, you can still choose what is being used even when cgo is enabled. See https://pkg.go.dev/net#hdr-Name_Resolution, use build tags to compile the one you want, or try GODEBUG at runtime.

Comment: Using `-tags netgo` doesn't make a difference. FWIW envvars appear don't do anything to Go internals when it's a shared lib, my guess is due to main not being used. Time to fall back to C++ for this module. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @MikeSummers I am pretty sure it's not related to DNS and you have the same problem described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33248427/how-to-debug-c-shared-library-written-in-go-it-hangs-on-net-call I cant figure out the suitable solution to this on my own, but if you do, please let me know.

Comment: @milkpirate I've not tried this since- I wrote the Apache Module in C++. If I ever revisit this _and_ solve it I'll be sure to let you know.

Comment: @MikeSummers sure, I got a little further, if you're still interested read on: In the mentioned threads I posted links to golang issues clarifying the problem, you need to check how Apache loads the modules, the order of `fork` and `dlopen` must be like. If its the other way round the runtime wont be available.