# runtime.gcBgMarkStartWorkers: can't run gc correctly and nginx has no any response

Tags: c, go, nginx

```
$ go version
go version go1.19 linux/amd64
$ go env
go env
GO111MODULE="on"
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/root/.cache/go-build"
GOENV="/root/.config/go/env"
GOEXE=""
GOEXPERIMENT=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOINSECURE=""
GOMODCACHE="/root/go/pkg/mod"
GONOPROXY="*.qianxin-inc.cn"
GONOSUMDB="*.qianxin-inc.cn"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/root/go"
GOPRIVATE="*.qianxin-inc.cn"
GOPROXY="https://goproxy.cn,direct"
GOROOT="/root/go"
GOSUMDB="sum.golang.org"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/root/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GOVCS=""
GOVERSION="go1.19"
GCCGO="gccgo"
GOAMD64="v1"
AR="ar"
CC="gcc"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD="/dev/null"
GOWORK=""
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -Wl,--no-gc-sections -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build273339992=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches"
```

My program throws some errors, which I am unable to resolve.

It is written in C, while some functions are writte in Go.

I use `go build -o libtest.so -buildmode=c-shared xxx.go xxx.go;``

After executing the command, I get a `libtest.so`, then I call it by `dlopen` in the C program.

My C program run as a plugin in nginx.

After calling the Go function, the nginx has no any response. I use gdb to debug it, and found below backtrace:

```
(gdb) bt
#0 runtime.futex () at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/sys_linux_amd64.s:520
#1 0x00007fff23c550f6 in runtime.futexsleep (addr=0xfffffffffffffe00, val=0, ns=140733793710979) at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/os_linux.go:44
#2 0x00007fff23c35667 in runtime.notetsleep_internal (n=0x7fff23dc66e8 <runtime.work+232>, ns=-1) at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/lock_futex.go:183
#3 0x00007fff23c35785 in runtime.notetsleepg (n=0x7fff23dc66e8 <runtime.work+232>, ns=-1) at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/lock_futex.go:237
#4 0x00007fff23c41338 in runtime.gcBgMarkStartWorkers () at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mgc.go:1126
#5 0x00007fff23c3fd92 in runtime.gcStart (trigger=...) at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mgc.go:637
#6 0x00007fff23c36e3d in runtime.mallocgc (size=565248, typ=0x7fff23cfd160, needzero=true) at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/malloc.go:1174
#7 0x00007fff23c6dfaa in runtime.growslice (et=, old=..., cap=) at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/slice.go:267
#8 0x00007fff23c918ef in regexp/syntax.(*compiler).inst (c=0xc000044bf8, op=) at /usr/local/go/src/regexp/syntax/compile.go:164
#9 regexp/syntax.(*compiler).rune (c=0xc000044bf8, r=[]int32 = {...}, flags=212) at /usr/local/go/src/regexp/syntax/compile.go:273
#10 0x00007fff23c90f1e in regexp/syntax.(*compiler).compile (c=0xc000044bf8, re=0xc000190000) at /usr/local/go/src/regexp/syntax/compile.go:101
#11 0x00007fff23c8f805 in regexp/syntax.Compile (re=0xc000190000) at /usr/local/go/src/regexp/syntax/compile.go:74
#12 0x00007fff23ca4a9a in regexp.compile (expr=,
mode=, longest=false) at /usr/local/go/src/regexp/regexp.go:178
#13 0x00007fff23ca5591 in regexp.Compile (expr="") at /usr/local/go/src/regexp/regexp.go:133
#14 regexp.MustCompile (str="") at /usr/local/go/src/regexp/regexp.go:309
#15 0x00007fff23ca8e0a in main.CheckPostAddress (buf=, bufLen=) at /root/codes/di_rechk/rechk.go:540
#16 0x00007fff23ca9a88 in _cgoexp_67df0785bef2_CheckPostAddress (a=0x7fffffffc740) at _cgo_gotypes.go:162
#17 0x00007fff23c2e21a in runtime.cgocallbackg1 (fn=0x7fff23ca9a60 <_cgoexp_67df0785bef2_CheckPostAddress>, frame=0x7fffffffc740, ctxt=0)
at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/cgocall.go:306
#18 0x00007fff23c2dee9 in runtime.cgocallbackg (fn=0x7fff23ca9a60 <_cgoexp_67df0785bef2_CheckPostAddress>, frame=0x7fffffffc740, ctxt=0)
at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/cgocall.go:232
#19 0x00007fff23c83791 in runtime.cgocallbackg (fn=0x7fff23ca9a60 <_cgoexp_67df0785bef2_CheckPostAddress>, frame=0x7fffffffc740, ctxt=0)
at :1
#20 0x00007fff23c813f3 in runtime.cgocallback () at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:915
#21 0x00007fff23c81601 in runtime.goexit () at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1581
#22 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()

(gdb) info goroutines

    17 syscall runtime.notetsleepg
    2 waiting runtime.gopark
    3 waiting runtime.gopark
    4 waiting runtime.gopark
    19 runnable runtime.gcBgMarkWorker

(gdb) goroutine 17 bt
#0 runtime.notetsleepg (n=0x7fff23dc66e8 <runtime.work+232>, ns=-1) at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/lock_futex.go:237
#1 0x00007fff23c41338 in runtime.gcBgMarkStartWorkers () at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mgc.go:1126
#2 0x00007fff23c3fd92 in runtime.gcStart (trigger=...) at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mgc.go:637
#3 0x00007fff23c36e3d in runtime.mallocgc (size=565248, typ=0x7fff23cfd160, needzero=true) at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/malloc.go:1174
#4 0x00007fff23c6dfaa in runtime.growslice (et=, old=..., cap=) at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/slice.go:267
#5 0x00007fff23c918ef in regexp/syntax.(*compiler).inst (c=0xc000044bf8, op=) at /usr/local/go/src/regexp/syntax/compile.go:164
#6 regexp/syntax.(*compiler).rune (c=0xc000044bf8, r=[]int32 = {...}, flags=212) at /usr/local/go/src/regexp/syntax/compile.go:273
#7 0x00007fff23c90f1e in regexp/syntax.(*compiler).compile (c=0xc000044bf8, re=0xc00022a000) at /usr/local/go/src/regexp/syntax/compile.go:101
#8 0x00007fff23c8f805 in regexp/syntax.Compile (re=0xc00022a000) at /usr/local/go/src/regexp/syntax/compile.go:74
#9 0x00007fff23ca4a9a in regexp.compile (expr=,
mode=, longest=false) at /usr/local/go/src/regexp/regexp.go:178
#10 0x00007fff23ca5591 in regexp.Compile (expr=""") at /usr/local/go/src/regexp/regexp.go:133
#11 regexp.MustCompile (str=""") at /usr/local/go/src/regexp/regexp.go:309
#12 0x00007fff23ca8e0a in main.CheckPostAddress (buf=, bufLen=) at /root/codes/di_rechk/rechk.go:540
#13 0x00007fff23ca9a88 in _cgoexp_67df0785bef2_CheckPostAddress (a=0x7fffffffc740) at _cgo_gotypes.go:162
#14 0x00007fff23c2e21a in runtime.cgocallbackg1 (fn=0x7fff23ca9a60 <_cgoexp_67df0785bef2_CheckPostAddress>, frame=0x7fffffffc740, ctxt=0)
at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/cgocall.go:306
#15 0x00007fff23c2dee9 in runtime.cgocallbackg (fn=0x7fff23ca9a60 <_cgoexp_67df0785bef2_CheckPostAddress>, frame=0x7fffffffc740, ctxt=0)
at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/cgocall.go:232
#16 0x00007fff23c83791 in runtime.cgocallbackg (fn=0x7fff23ca9a60 <_cgoexp_67df0785bef2_CheckPostAddress>, frame=0x7fffffffc740, ctxt=0)
at :1
#17 0x00007fff23c813f3 in runtime.cgocallback () at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:915
#18 0x00007fff23c81601 in runtime.goexit () at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1581
#19 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()

(gdb) goroutine 2 bt
#0 runtime.gopark (unlockf=, lock=, reason=, traceEv=, traceskip=)
at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:367
#1 0x00007fff23c5b86d in runtime.goparkunlock (reason=, traceEv=, traceskip=, lock=)
at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:372
#2 runtime.forcegchelper () at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:306
#3 0x00007fff23c81601 in runtime.goexit () at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1581
#4 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
(gdb) goroutine 3 bt
#0 runtime.gopark (unlockf=, lock=, reason=, traceEv=, traceskip=)
at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:367
#1 0x00007fff23c48ee8 in runtime.goparkunlock (reason=, traceEv=, traceskip=, lock=)
at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:372
#2 runtime.bgsweep () at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mgcsweep.go:163
#3 0x00007fff23c81601 in runtime.goexit () at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1581
#4 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
(gdb) goroutine 4 bt
#0 runtime.gopark (unlockf=, lock=, reason=, traceEv=, traceskip=)
at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:367
#1 0x00007fff23c46fed in runtime.goparkunlock (reason=, traceEv=, traceskip=, lock=)
at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:372
#2 runtime.bgscavenge () at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mgcscavenge.go:265
#3 0x00007fff23c81601 in runtime.goexit () at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1581
#4 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
(gdb) goroutine 19 bt
#0 runtime.gcBgMarkWorker () at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mgc.go:1166
#1 0x00007fff23c81601 in runtime.goexit () at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1581
#2 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()

(gdb) info threads
Id Target Id Frame
1 Thread 0x7ffff7966b80 (LWP 2024707) "nginx" runtime.futex () at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/sys_linux_amd64.s:520

    2 Thread 0x7ffef1ffb700 (LWP 2024717) "nginx" 0x00007ffff7a483bf in __GI___clock_nanosleep (clock_id=clock_id@entry=0, flags=flags@entry=0,
    req=req@entry=0x7ffef1ffae80, rem=rem@entry=0x0) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/clock_nanosleep.c:78
    3 Thread 0x7ffef27fc700 (LWP 2024718) "ZMQbg/Reaper" 0x00007ffff7a8a5ce in epoll_wait (epfd=42, events=events@entry=0x7ffef27fb200,
    maxevents=maxevents@entry=256, timeout=timeout@entry=-1) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/epoll_wait.c:30
    4 Thread 0x7ffef2ffd700 (LWP 2024719) "ZMQbg/IO/0" 0x00007ffff7a8a5ce in epoll_wait (epfd=44, events=events@entry=0x7ffef2ffc200,
    maxevents=maxevents@entry=256, timeout=timeout@entry=-1) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/epoll_wait.c:30
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem,i get the answer from [How to debug C-shared library (written in Go) - it hangs on net call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33248427/how-to-debug-c-shared-library-written-in-go-it-hangs-on-net-call,if) you want to know the reason,please visit the website.

my program is running on master-worker model,and the problem occurs in the work process.
I use dlopen function to open the so file before fork child process,so the child process has no go runtime threads.